# AngularJS 1.7 - templateUrl displays url in view instead of the template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

### Summary

I'm trying to convert my angularjs components/directives over to TypeScript. Unfortunately, the `templateUrl` property doesn't display the template that's passed to it. Instead, it literally displays a partial path the template.

### Code

```js
class JumpPagerController {
...
    }
}

JumpPagerController.$inject = ['$timeout'];
export const jumpPagerComponent = {
    templateUrl: './jump-pager.component.html',
    controller: JumpPagerController,
    bindings: {
        pagerPlaceholder: '@?',
        pagerCurrentPage: '=',
        pagerItemsPerPage: '=',
        pagerTotalItems: '=',
        pagerChange: '&'
    }
};
```

#### Expected

[image]

#### Actual

[image]

### What I've Tried

- Passing in the baseUrl (didn't have high hopes here:

  - `` templateUrl: `${baseUrl}/jump-pager.component.html` ``
  - `templateUrl: localhost:8080/jump-pager.component.html`
- `template: require('...')` works, but would require me to reconfigure webpack and then modify all other cases of `templateUrl` in `.js` files. This isn't an option
- I've reviewed similar questions but no one else seems to be having quite the same issue. They're all either using JavaScript instead of TypeScript, or they're only having an issue with the template not rendering and don't seem to be getting the weird problem with the template path being displayed.

### Recap

So you can see that I'm at a loss. **What is the correct way to use templateUrl on an angularjs component using typescript and webpack?**

Comment: Using a `/` prefix will make the path relative to the domain, if that's where the file really is—have you tried this? (i.e. `/jump-pager.component.html`) Though something tells me you've got this template file nested in a folder for the component.

Comment: I am considering html and ts is in same folder. So you can directly use `'jump-pager.component.html'`

Comment: The assumptions are correct. All the components .ts/.scss/.html live in their respective folders, so the assumption would be `./jump-pager.component.html` or `jump-pager.component.html` would work.

Comment: On a side note, I found a way to use `template: require('./jump-pager.html')` in my TypeScript without breaking other components still written in JavaScript by adding a second `html-loader` configuration in my webpack.config.js. One has `issuer: /\.js$/` and the unchanged configuration, while the other one has `issuer: /\.ts$/` with the recommended boilerplate configuration for html-loader. It seems to work as expected.